# Look and Feel in List in java

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I Write a small program that will switch among number of L&F
Just choose L&F from list and button will looks different.

but not change when Second chance

and I am beginner with java :)

this my code

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:

int selectedIndices[] = jList1.getSelectedIndices();
try {
for (int j = 0; j < selectedIndices.length; j++){
if(j == 0){
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
   SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
             this.pack();
}
if(j == 1){
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
 SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
              this.pack();
 }
 if(j == 2){
 UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
 SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
             // this.pack();
}
if(j == 3){
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
  SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
             this.pack();
}
}
}
catch (Exception e) {
               } 
     }
```

Comment: Do you ever have more than 1 selected index? Using j which is just an index variable doesn't seem correct...

Answer (score 3):

If only one item is selected (I suppose it is the case), your code will always select MotifLookAndFeel:

- selectedIndices.length is 1
- therefore j, in your for loop, will only take 0 as a value
- MotifLookAndFeel is selected.

You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
switch (jList1.getSelectedIndex()) {
    case 0:
       //select 1st L&F
       return;
    case 1:
       //select 2nd L&F
       return;
    case 2:
       //select 3rd L&F
       return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with this code.

1. You loop over an array `for (int j = 0; j < selectedIndices.length; j++)` but you never use the entries in the array `selectedIndices[j]`. Instead you just use `j`.
2. Now you have hardcoded that when `j==0` you will use `MotifLookAndFeel`. Normally you would use the selectedIndex to retrieve the data from the list (=a identifier for the look and feel), and use that identifier to change the look and feel
3. It is very bad practice to just surround your code with `try{} catch( Exception e ){}`. For instance you catch all `Exception`s, checked exceptions and runtime exceptions. Further, you do not do anything with the exception. At least put a `e.printStackTrace()` call in the `catch` block so you actually know that something went wrong
4. In my personal experience, switching from look-and-feel goes well from the standard look-and-feel (Metal) to the System specific look-and-feel. But switching from Metal - OS specific - Nimbus - Metal - .... leads to weird results.

Just to get you going, I would write that code more like (non-compiling pseudo-code to illustrate my issues mentioned above)

```
//where the list is created 
//only allow single selection since I cannot set multiple L&F at the same time      
jList1.setSelectionMode( ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION );

//button handling
int selectedIndex = jList1.getSelectedIndex();
if ( selectedIndex == -1 ) { return; } //no selection
MyLookAndFeelIdentifier identifier = jList1.getModel().getElementAt( selectedIndex );   
try{   
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel( identifier.getLookAndFeel() ); 
} catch ( UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e ){    
   e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: *"OS specific - Nimbus - Metal - .... leads to weird results."*  Nimbus is Notorious for introducing weird GUI artifacts.  :(

Comment: @AndrewThompson I also encounter this with other L&Fs (Motif, Kunstoff, ... ). Switching from metal to one of those and back is no problem, but switching from non-metal to another non-metal almost always results in artifacts. I have the impression JDK1.6 improved this (1.4 and 1.5 were simply a disaster), but it is still far from perfect

Answer (score 0):

The book Java How To Program has a similar program example. [Link1](http://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/cis5100/examples/ch22/fig22_17_18/LookAndFeelFrame.java), [Link2](http://www.cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/cis5100/examples/ch22/fig22_17_18/LookAndFeelDemo.java)